# Issue with flexbox / gap in Bootstrap website under breadcrumbs

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I got an issue with one of my pages based on Bootstrap which I do not really understand.
We added recently breadcrumbs (also BS) for navigation, but on some pages there is a big gap between the breadcrumbs and the main content as you can see on the following page:
[Page with issue](https://docs-beta.otc.t-systems.com/umn/elastic-cloud-server/instances/index.html)

But there are also pages which do not have this issue and I can't find the reason why this happens:
[Page without issue](https://docs-beta.otc.t-systems.com/umn/elastic-cloud-server/instances/viewing_ecs_information/viewing_failures.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your layout is totaly ***wrong***

in your case use this :

```
.row{
align-content: flex-start;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, what else is wrong?

Comment: for example for your ```left-sidebar``` you should give a ```width``` and for your ```row flex-start``` you shouldn't use ```.row``` you should put it inside a ```div``` and give ```padding-left``` to your ```div``` so it can be responsive and for layout like this don't put your breadcrumbs in a ```.row``` it will mess up your layout like this

Comment: Thanks for your hints. We will have a look on how to refactor the whole side.

Answer (score 0):

in `.row` add:

```css
.row {
   align-content: flex-start;
}
```